# how to automatic page break in long mixed html content

Tags: javascript, python, html, css, django

I have problem with my project when i need print long content. My project based on django framwork. My content is mixed of table and `<p>` etc .... My application should page break automatic when content is overfllow of my A4 page

Comment: Please clarify your issue and what you would like answered. What tools and software are you using? What is displaying now and what would you like to display?

Comment: thanks for yout answer

Comment: Why do you want to page break? What is the purpose? 

Do you want to print it or convert to pdf or export ?

Comment: i want to print this html report . my report has mixed content   my first way for solve this problem break per 100 word but i have html table in this report  and this way not solve

Answer (score 1):

There is a print media properties which are page-break-before, page-break-after and page-break-inside. You can use them as your use CSS for HTML pages but these properties should be used only within print media.

```
@media print {......}
```

Quick reference url : https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/p/page-break/

Comment: my data is dynamic and i dont know where set page break    my problem is how can i calc content for this page and split content to seperate page

Comment: Agree, your content might be dynamic but they will definitely wrapped inside some container (HTML tag). So you can write the page break based on that. You can refer my sample code for page break at github @ https://github.com/itsselvam/timeline.Portfolio. Do check the source code, none of the <li> are breaking between pages.